# Printing Error-An error occurred during this operation-RDLC-Report viewer Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc, reportviewer

Hi I am trying to generate a report in wpf using report viewer.

```
<WindowsFormsHost>        
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="RVReciept"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Someting when I click on print button I get error even export button does not work.
[Print Option of Report View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9weg.png)
Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt9j9.png)

I could'nt found any solution it.Please guide me.

Comment: Hello, did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. But I use WinForms. I've spent many hours to solving and googling. But in the end my problem was this code:

```
[STAThread]
private static async Task Main()
```

Never do this when using this component. Use only non-async method Main.